# Painting Japanese characters using Arial fonts with method drawString(..) (Graphics2D)

Tags: java, swing, graphics, fonts

A `String` can be painted like that:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

    try {

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        g2d.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 12));//Japanese characters are visible
        //g2d.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));//Japanese characters are not visible (squares only)

        g2d.drawString("Berryz工房 『ROCKエロティック』(Berryz Kobo[Erotic ROCK]) （MV）", 10, 45);

    } finally {
        g2d.dispose();
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I do `g2d.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));` - Japanese characters are not visible, just squares instead:

[image]

And if I set font like `g2d.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 12));` - everything works fine:

[image]

For example, in MS WordPad the characters are visible if Arial font is selected:

[image]

But I want to use `Arial` font. Maybe I have to detect Japanese character and switch to different font, and then back again?

Comment: [Arial Unicode](http://www.fonts.com/font/monotype/arial-unicode) should be able to draw Katakana, but it is not cheap :D. About your WordPad example: if I use  Word, then it will switch to *MS Gothic* for the Katakana/Kanji and uses Arial for the over characters.

Comment: You probably need to use [Font.canDisplayUpTo(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#canDisplayUpTo%28java.lang.String%29) to check up to where Arial can display, then switch over to Japanese font and repeat again until the whole string is written. Wordpad and MS Word will fallback to some default font for certain type of script when the main font chosen cannot render the character.

Comment: Yes,  `Font.canDisplayUpTo(String)` will help here, but how to implement it.. :) Another puzzle, but at least it is possible. Arial Unicode - could be great, but how much it will cost to allow it to ship with commercial applications?..

Comment: `new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12)`  Try instead `new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 12)`  which should be Arial on Windows at least.

Comment: Super! :) Now I can see in Arial, and Japanese characters also visible. I suppose it will work not only on Windows?

Comment: *"I suppose it will work not only on Windows?"*  Nope.  That's the great thing about logical fonts.  On OS X for instance, it will use another sans serif (without decorations) font such as Helvetica, and use whatever other local fonts it might need for any scripts not covered by that sans serif font.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works using the logical fonts. `SANS_SERIF` will be Arial (primarily) on Windows.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FontTestWithJapaneseCharacters {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    class PaintingSurface extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 20);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 12));
            g2d.drawString("Berryz工房 『ROCKエロティック』"
                    + "(Berryz Kobo[Erotic ROCK]) （MV）", 10, 15);
        }
    }

    FontTestWithJapaneseCharacters() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }

        ui = new PaintingSurface();
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                FontTestWithJapaneseCharacters o
                        = new FontTestWithJapaneseCharacters();

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Font test with Japanese characters");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be very nice to know how it performs on other platforms. Thanks indeed for help.