# Different font for Shift-JIS encoded string

Tags: java, character-encoding, character, non-ascii-characters, shift-jis

In Java, I am reading an array of bytes from a file encoded in Shift-JIS format, but the "style" of the characters in the acquired string looks different than normal strings (wider?).
Here is an example of what I mean for the "P" letter:
Ｐ - P
As you can see the first one in Shift-JIS looks different than the second one. Is there a way to use "normal" characters even for Shift-JIS strings?
I am using this piece of code to perform the conversion:

```
String jis = new String(byteArray, Charset.forName("Shift_JIS"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, These are different characters. The first `Ｐ` is the `Fullwidth Latin Capital Letter P` in Unicode, from Japanese JIS X 0208 charset (U+FF30). The second `P` is the `Latin Capital Letter P` from ASCII (U+0050).

So, you have to convert fullwidth characters to halfwidth characters. You can do this with ICU4J's [Transliterator](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/Transliterator.html).

```java
Transliterator transliterator = Transliterator.getInstance("Halfwidth-Fullwidth");
String result = transliterator.transliterate("Ｐ - P");
System.out.println(result); // You will get "P - P"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working. There is only one little mistake in the answer: it should be Fullwidth-Halfwidth, right?

Answer (score 0):

**The following tables show the `Japanese` encoding sets supported by J2SE 5.0**. The canonical names used by the new java.nio APIs are in many cases not the same as those used in the java.io and java.lang APIs. You can use another japanese font.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Canonical Name for  | Canonical Name for java.io  |               Description               |
|   java.nio API     |      and java.lang API      |                                         |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      EUC-JP        |           EUC_JP            | JISX 0201, 0208 and 0212, EUC encoding  | 
|                    |                             |               Japanese                  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    ISO-2022-JP     |         ISO2022JP           | JIS X 0201, 0208, in ISO 2022 form,     | 
|                    |                             |               Japanese                  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      Shift_JIS     |             SJIS            |            Shift-JIS, Japanese          | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    windows-31j     |           MS932             |             Windows Japanese            | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  x-euc-jp-linux    |        EUC_JP_LINUX         | JISX 0201, 0208, EUC encoding Japanese  | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   x-eucJP-Open     |       EUC_JP_Solaris        | JISX 0201, 0208, 0212, EUC encoding     | 
|                    |                             |               Japanese                  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     x-IBM33722     |           Cp33722           | IBM-eucJP - Japanese (superset of 5050) | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      x-IBM930      |            Cp930            | Japanese Katakana-Kanji mixed with 4370 | 
|                    |                             |         UDC, superset of 5026           |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      x-IBM939      |            Cp939            | Japanese Latin Kanji mixed with 4370    | 
|                    |                             |         UDC, superset of 5035           |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      x-IBM942      |            Cp942            |  IBM OS/2 Japanese, superset of Cp932   | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      x-IBM943      |            Cp943            | IBM OS/2 Japanese, superset of Cp932    | 
|                    |                             |         and Shift-JIS                   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Resource Link:

[Painting Japanese characters using Arial fonts with method drawString(..) (Graphics2D)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28853176/painting-japanese-characters-using-arial-fonts-with-method-drawstring-graph)

Comment: I tried them all, for many of them the generated string has again that strange look, for some others the strings aren't encoded correctly at all.